# Does a filter form a natural basis for a topology?

Tags: soft-question, metric-spaces, p-adic-number-theory

The subset of the 2-adic units which are also conventional integers $\mathbb{Q}_2^{\times}\cap\mathbb{N}$ is filtered by the function $f(x)=2x+1$, by which I mean if we set the function's domain to $\mathbb{N}_2^{\times}=\{1,3,5,7,9,11,13,\ldots\}$ then only the principal units $U^{(1)}=\{3,7,11,\ldots\}$ are in its range, which is a proper subset of its domain and subsequent applications of $f$ continue to generate further proper subsets of their predecessor.

We can continue indefinitely to generate $U^{(n)}=\{x:x\equiv2^{n+1}-1\mod2^{n+1}\}$ and every odd integer is filtered out at some point.

> Does this filter naturally induce a metric/topology on $\mathbb{Q}_2\cap\mathbb{N}$?

The kind of thing I have in mind for my purposes is (but I don't want to reinvent the wheel here); define a valuation $x_{2\times}$ such that the valuation of $x$ is the highest $n$ for which $U^{(n)}$ contains $x$:

$x_{2\times}=\max\{n:x\in U^{(n)}\}$

Then the distance metric $d(x,y)$ says two odd numbers are close if the $n$ at which they leave the order of units is close:

$d(x,y)=\lvert x_{2\times}-y_{2\times}\rvert$

My motivation to some degree is to define a metric which is orthogonal to the 2-adic metric.  I guess I'm asking if this makes sense, does it define a meaningful topology, and is this a rehashing of something which already exists which I may be able to study rather than start from scratch?

Also, I use the example of 2-adics but I will need to use this in the 2, 3 and 4-adic metric spaces so I'm not just looking for the obvious modular arithmetic answer for the special case of the 2 adics.

EDIT: I now realise it defines a pseudometric. Does this form a basis for some topology?

Comment: Could you maybe give a definition of $\mathbb{Q}_2 \cap \mathbb{N}$? If (assuming from your tags), $\mathbb{Q}_2$ is supposed to be a $p$-adic number field and $\mathbb{N}$ is embedded into it as a subset of $\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}_2$, this intersection should be just $\mathbb{N}$. But then there is no reason to use $\mathbb{Q}_2$ at all, if you only want to talk about natural numbers. Thus, I'm a little confused here...

Comment: @DirkLiebhold the point of $\mathbb{Q}_2\cap\mathbb{N}$ is that I'm thinking p-adically but I'm temporarily restricting myself to the integer values as it simplifies the set of numbers I'm working with and reveals the structure more clearly. Once I have some theorems in $\cap\mathbb{N}$ I may well extend.

Comment: In other words, for any $x$, your "valuation" $x_{2\times}$ is just $v_2(x+1) -1$ with the usual $2$-adic valuation $v_2$. What would you want to do with this that you can't do easier with $v_2$ itself? Also, your $d$ certainly does not define a metric.

Comment: Thanks @TorstenSchoeneberg . I improved/changed what's in the brackets.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg pseudometric? In fact I think this is a part of the answer. A filter induces a pseudometric, assuming it filters out multiple elements at every step. Does that induce a topology?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg in terms of what's easier; all of these numbers are odd so $v_2=0$ but $x_{2\times}$ varies. And I hope it will be useful for proof by induction over the residues mod $2^n$ because by my valuation $\{1\mod2\}\setminus \{1\mod4\}$ has valuation one less than $\{1\mod4\}\setminus \{1\mod8\}$ and so on. My ultimate objective is to show that the orbit of the function $3x+2^{v_2(x)}$ is in some sense orthogonal to the function $4x+1$ in the odd integers away from the vicinity of the number $1$.

Comment: I think the topological space you get is a countable disjoint union of countable sets each of which carries the trivial (indiscrete) topology, and the open sets are precisely the disjoint sub-unions.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg thanks. Does that make the levels of the filter one higher and one lower, the boundary of any given open set?

Comment: No. In that topology, the open sets are exactly the closed sets, so the boundary of any open set is empty.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg thanks